# LINQ - GroupBy a key of paired object, then separate the grouped object into list of 2 objects?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I have a list of objects (in pair, in one, `IsApproved` is true, and the other, `IsApproved` is false, i.e.:

```
public class Object
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MatchId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
}
```

The list would be something like:

`1 123ABC SomeName True`

`2 123ABC SomeElse False`

`3 321CBA Name2 True`

`4 321CBA Name3 False`

`5 987ASD NameName True`

`6 987ASD TestTest False`

I would need to be able to group them by `MatchId`, then separate them so that I have a new list like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public List<PairedObject> PairedObjects { get; set; }
}

public class PairedObject
{
    public Object IsApproved { get; set; }
    public Object NotApproved { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestion on how to do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: `IsApproved` and `NotApproved` are supposed to be collections of the corresponding items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list.GroupBy(o => o.MatchId)
    .Select(g => new PairedObject
                     {
                         IsApproved = g.First(o => o.IsApproved),
                         NotApproved = g.First(o => !o.IsApproved)
                     });
```

Comment: I would replace First with Single and dont forget about checking if there are more than 2 in group. Murphy's laws and all..